# Going to another activity from dialog box

Tags: android

I want to go to my sign-in activity after confirming logout from alert box, but it is not working for me. Can anyone help me to sort out?

Here is **navigation.java** class

```
final Dialog mydialog = new Dialog(this);
mydialog.setTitle("Confirm Logout");
mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.logoutdialog);
Button yesoption = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yes);
Button nooption = (Button) findViewById(R.id.no);
yesoption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent login = new Intent(navigation.this, signin.class);
        startActivity(login);
        finish();
    }

});
nooption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mydialog.dismiss();

    }
});

mydialog.show();
}
```

Comment: might you please appending the exception into your question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the dialog to get the instances of your button view from your custom layout. Try it.

```
    final Dialog mydialog = new Dialog(this);
    mydialog.setTitle("Confirm Logout");
    mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.logoutdialog);
    Button yesoption = (Button)mydialog.findViewById(R.id.yes);
    Button nooption = (Button)mydialog.findViewById(R.id.no);

    yesoption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            Intent login = new Intent(navigation.this , signin.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(login);
            finish();
        }

    });

    nooption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mydialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    mydialog.show();
}
```

Comment: ThankYou sir You saved my life :-p

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it helped you. Thanks